# ffmpeg: Streaming with RTSP and recording at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

My goal is to stream a part of my desktop to a remote machine, and to record the sent stream at the same time.
The streaming technology chosen is the RTSP protocol with FFserver as rtsp server.

I already succeed the streaming part with ffmpeg, but now I'm trying to record the stream at the same time. To do so, I'm trying to use the tee pseudo-muxer as referenced here:
http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee

Unfortunately, I'm having an error message when launching my command which is the following:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug  -f alsa -ac 2 -thread_queue_size 512 -ar 44100 -i hw:0 \
-f x11grab -framerate 30 -show_region 1 -video_size 800x480 -thread_queue_size 512 -i :0.0 \
-f tee -c:v libx264 -c:a mp3 -pix_fmt yuv422p  -flags +global_header -map 1:v -map 0:a \
"test.mp4|[f=ffm]http://localhost:8000/feed.ffm/"
```

And here is the output:

```
  ffmpeg version 3.4-1~xenial1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~xenial1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nvenc --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libopencv --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1512038836.756092, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Input #1, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1512038836.789836, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 800x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5621206c0180] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x5621206c0180] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.1, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x5621206c0180] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[tee @ 0x5621206bef60] Slave '[f=ffm]http://localhost:8000/feed.ffm/': error writing header: Broken pipe
[tee @ 0x5621206bef60] Slave muxer #1 failed, aborting.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 

Broken pipe
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

I also tried with f=rtsp, with no chance and this error message:

```
[tee @ 0x559b26ea2f40] Slave '[f=rtsp]http://localhost:8000/feed.ffm/': error writing header: Invalid data found when processing input
[tee @ 0x559b26ea2f40] Slave muxer #1 failed, aborting.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

FFserver configuration:

```
<Feed feed.ffm>
   File /tmp/feed.ffm
   FileMaxSize 20M
</Feed>

<Stream test.mp4>
   Feed feed.ffm
   Format rtp
   VideoSize 800x480
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 25
   VideoFrameRate 30
   VideoBitRate 8000
   VideoCodec libx264
   PixelFormat yuv422p


   #h264 options
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
   AVOptionVideo preset ultrafast
   AVOptionVideo crf 25
   AVOptionVideo profile high422
   AVOptionVideo tune zerolatency

   NoAudio
</Stream>
```

"Slave '[f=ffm]http://localhost:8000/feed.ffm/': error writing header: Broken pipe" is the key, but I can't figure what is wrong in my command. Without tee, it works flawlessly.

I did many searches and cannot find the problem yet, so I'm asking here.

Thanks,
Barzou.

Comment: Your ffmpeg and ffserver are old. Try [downloading a newer version](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Indeed ffmpeg/ffserver packets are old in ubuntu/debian repositories. I just updated to a newer version (3.4.1), but the problem remains the same. However the error message seems a bit more verbose, I'm updating the original post to show the new output.

Comment: I don't see your actual command.

Comment: Oops, I deleted it by mistake while editing the post. Should be OK now.

Comment: I don't know. Almost no ffserver questions ever get answered because almost nobody uses it and the alleged users who do don't provide answers. It is unmaintained and it planned for removal from FFmpeg. I suggest finding an alternative.

Comment: I'am Having same issue have you manged to solve it !@Barzou